# How to check my implementation of a function which generates an infinite list?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

> Write a function that takes the function `f` and the number `n` and returns the list `[f n, f (n + 1), f (n + 2), f (n + 3), f (n + 4) ... ]`.

Here is my solution:

```
func f n = f n : func f (n+1)
```

But I'm not sure that it is correct. How can I check my implementation?

Comment: As you are generating an infinite list, you can use `take` to examine finite prefixes of different lengths. For example, does `take 5 (func (+1) 3) == [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`?

Comment: @Silver I believe your solution is correct (although I think you have a typo — you wrote `funck` instead of `func` in the body of the function). But as @chepner said, you should probably test your function using `take`.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected a typo. As for the "take", I took this note. Your opinion was important to me.

Comment: Another way to write this is `map f [n..]`. A property you could test is:`take k (drop m (func f n)) == take k (func f (n+m))`: the first `k` elements should be the same whether you start at `n+m` or start at `n` and skip `m` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a **co-inductive** proof. Co-inductive reasoning is similar to inductive reasoning, but it allows for "infinite" structures. It's a natural choice for reasoning about things like data streams and infinite lists.

The property you want `func` to have is something like

```hs
∀ f : Int -> a, ∀ n : Int, ∀ i : Int, (i >= 0 ⟹ (func f n) !! i == f (n + i))
```

Proving something by co-induction is similar to induction: you assume it as a co-inductive hypothesis for all substructures, and then prove it for the superstructure. Since there is only one definition for `func`, there is only only such proof obligation.

This means that, if you could prove

```
∀ f : Int -> a, ∀ n : Int, ∀ i : Int, (i ≥ 0 ⟹ (func f n) !! i == f (n + i))
⟹
∀ f : Int -> a, ∀ n : Int, ∀ i : Int, (i ≥ 0 ⟹ (f n : (func f (n + 1))) !! i == f (n + i))
```

then you would prove that your function definition is correct.

Since you could actually prove the above statement, your function definition is correct.